# How to use custom exception handler with ProblemDetails?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling

I'm looking into upgrading an API to use the new `ProblemDetails` functionality in AspNetCore 7/8.

If I use the standard `app.UseExceptionHandler();` it works fine with both `Accept: application/json` and `Accept: application/xml`

My controller just does `throw new Exception("message from exception");`

```bash
curl https://localhost:7089/Test -H "Accept: application/json" 
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.6.1",
    "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
    "status": 500,
    "traceId": "00-7165c3ae88dba50c1c055a15f2bcf893-79d5c49179a9b30c-00"
}

curl https://localhost:7089/Test -H "Accept: application/xml"
<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807">
    <status>500</status>
    <title>An error occurred while processing your request.</title>
    <type>https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.6.1</type>
    <traceId>00-d8cf6db0704770b8badf2376da7c4f4c-4d6ead3e06d28c25-00</traceId>
</problem>
```

But if I try to add my own exception handler like [example documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0#produce-a-problemdetails-payload-for-exceptions)

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler(x => x.Run(async context =>
{
    if (context.Response.HasStarted)
        return;

    var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
    if (exception == null)
        throw new Exception("ExceptionHandler without exception!");

    var problemDetailsService = context.RequestServices.GetService<IProblemDetailsService>();
    await problemDetailsService.WriteAsync(new ProblemDetailsContext
    {
        HttpContext = context,
        ProblemDetails =
        {
            Title = exception.Message,
        }
    });
}));
```

it works fine with json but not with xml

```bash
curl https://localhost:7089/Test -H "Accept: application/json" 
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.6.1",
    "title": "message from exception",
    "status": 500
}

curl https://localhost:7089/Test -H "Accept: application/xml"
```

In the log I can see an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: Error: An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find a registered `IProblemDetailsWriter` that can write to the given context.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ProblemDetailsService.WriteAsync(ProblemDetailsContext context)

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Investigated it further and found a class [ProblemDetailsWrapper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/57a8a2ac464da4e7e5c1f73d1280e724204cfffb/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Xml/src/ProblemDetailsWrapper.cs#L15)

> "Wrapper class for  to enable it to be serialized by the xml formatters."

As far as I can tell it is added within `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` so I don't understand why it doesn't work with a custom exception handler.

I can get it to work (sort of, `CustomizeProblemDetails` is ignored) with code below but I think the problem is really something else.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IProblemDetailsWriter, XmlProblemDetailsWriter>();

...

public class XmlProblemDetailsWriter : IProblemDetailsWriter
{
    public bool CanWrite(ProblemDetailsContext context)
    {
        return context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString().Contains("application/xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public async ValueTask WriteAsync(ProblemDetailsContext context)
    {
        var problemDetails = context.ProblemDetails;
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

        var detailsWrapper = new ProblemDetailsWrapper(problemDetails);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(detailsWrapper.GetType());

        using (var writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, detailsWrapper);
            var xml = writer.ToString();
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
    }

    private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** A complete example
Program.cs

```cs
namespace TestProblemDetails;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

        var app = builder.Build();
        // Works with json and xml
        // app.UseExceptionHandler();
        // Works only with json
        app.UseExceptionHandler(x => x.Run(async context =>
        {
            if (context.Response.HasStarted)
                return;

            if (context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error is not { } exception)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("ExceptionHandler without exception!");

            var problemDetailsService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IProblemDetailsService>();
            await problemDetailsService.WriteAsync(new ProblemDetailsContext
            {
                HttpContext = context,
                ProblemDetails =
                {
                    Title = exception.Message,
                    Extensions = { ["traceId"] = context.TraceIdentifier }
                }
            });
        }));

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("This is a test exception");
    }
}
```

TestProblemDetails.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document, we should use IProblemDetailsWriter to support `application/xml`.

[image]

#### My test result

[image]

**Here is the sample I have test.**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace ProblemDetails
{
    public class XmlProblemDetailsWriter : IProblemDetailsWriter
    {
        public bool CanWrite(ProblemDetailsContext context)
        {
            return context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString().Contains("application/xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public async ValueTask WriteAsync(ProblemDetailsContext context)
        {
            var problemDetails = context.ProblemDetails;
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(problemDetails.GetType());

            using (var writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
            {
                var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
                serializer.Serialize(writer, problemDetails, namespaces);
                var xml = writer.ToString();
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }
        private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
        {
            public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

Register it

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace ProblemDetails
{
    public class XmlProblemDetailsWriter : IProblemDetailsWriter
    {
        public bool CanWrite(ProblemDetailsContext context)
        {
            return context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString().Contains("application/xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public async ValueTask WriteAsync(ProblemDetailsContext context)
        {
            var problemDetails = context.ProblemDetails;
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(problemDetails.GetType());

            using (var writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
            {
                var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
            serializer.Serialize(writer, problemDetails, namespaces);
                var xml = writer.ToString();
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }
        private class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
        {
            public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;

namespace ProblemDetails
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
            // add XmlProblemDetailsWriter service
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IProblemDetailsWriter, XmlProblemDetailsWriter>();


            var app = builder.Build();

            app.UseExceptionHandler(x => x.Run(async context =>
            {
                if (context.Response.HasStarted)
                    return;

                var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
                if (exception == null)
                    throw new Exception("ExceptionHandler without exception!");

                var problemDetailsService = context.RequestServices.GetService<IProblemDetailsService>();
                await problemDetailsService.WriteAsync(new ProblemDetailsContext
                {
                    HttpContext = context,
                    ProblemDetails =
        {
            Title = exception.Message,
        }
                });
            }));

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me "NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails.Extensions of type [...] because it is an interface." See my updated question.

Comment: Hi @adrianm, It's very strange, could you create a brand sample project which could reproduce the issue for me? Please hide the sensitive information and  I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Sample project in question. Don't understand how it could work for you. XmlSerializer does not support IDictionary so the error message is correct.

Comment: ok，@adrianm，so you mean my test result is wrong? Right? I just want to help you.

Comment: No, sorry, what I mean is that `new XmlSerializer(type)` will always throw if the type contain an interface. Since your code worked, that line wasn't executed or it triggered something else which worked around it.

Comment: Hi @adrianm I haven't seen you are using `builder.Services.AddTransient<IProblemDetailsWriter, XmlProblemDetailsWriter>();` in your program.cs, could you check it. By the way, I have confirmed the WriteAsync method was excuted.